# При переходе блока из display:inline-block в display:inline line-height не изменяется в меньшую сторону

Tags: css, inline, display

Я начинающий frontend-разработчик. При разработке резинового адаптива сайта столкнулся со следующей проблемой: при ширине экрана более 992px контент(текст) разделён на два тега "p" со свойством display:inline-block. При медиа-запросе max-width: 992px при замене display на inline (для того, чтобы абзацы были слитно (делаю pixelperfect)) - line-height (200%) не уменьшается в меньшую сторону (нужно уменьшить, чтобы подогнать под макет) В большую - меняется. В чём может быть причина?
[Видео кода в отладчике](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/LdB3VbCQCjQSeg)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: может быть ещё padding или margin у абзацев